# pandas plot bar with one of column values as Xaxis

Tags: python, pandas, plot

```
      A          B                  C             D         date
0  53936248   53928376            7840          2800     17-02-10
1  22936276   53928404            7840          2800     17-02-11
2  523763     53928404            7840          2800     17-02-12
```

HOW TO using pandas plot bar,the date values as Xaxis.

like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need first convert column `date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then to [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html).

Then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.year
df = df.set_index('date')
df.index.name= None
print (df)
             A         B     C     D
2010  53936248  53928376  7840  2800
2011  22936276  53928404  7840  2800
2012    523763  53928404  7840  2800

df.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

[image: graph]

If you wand plot `dates`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index('date')
df.index.name= None
print (df)
                   A         B     C     D
2010-02-17  53936248  53928376  7840  2800
2011-02-17  22936276  53928404  7840  2800
2012-02-17    523763  53928404  7840  2800

ax = df.plot.bar(rot=45)
ticklabels = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
plt.show()
```

[image: graph1]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `date` is already `datetime`

```
df.assign(year=df.date.dt.year) \
  .set_index('year').drop('date', 1) \
  .rename_axis([None]).plot.bar(rot=0)
```

[image]